# Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a perfect map. Show that if $Y$ is Lindelof, then $X$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a perfect map. Show that if $Y$ is Lindelof, then $X$ is compact.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_map

I have prove that given an open set $ U_{y} $ containing $ f^{-1}(y) $ for some $ y $, there exists an neighborhood $ W_{y} $ of $ y $ in $ Y $ such that $ f^{-1}(W) \subset U_{y}$.

Now, take some cover $ \{U_{\alpha} \} $ of $ X $.  For each $ y \in Y $, finitely many $ U_{\alpha} $ cover $ f^{-1}(y) $, so let $ V_{y} $ be the union of the sets in some finite subcover of $ f^{-1}(y) $, so $ V_{y} = U_{i_{1}} \cup \cdot\cdot\cdot U_{i_{n}} $.  Then, the sets $ f(V_{y}) $ each contain some open neighborhood $ W_{y} $ of $ y $ in $ Y $, and the collection $ \{ W_{y} \} $ covers $ Y $.  Since $ Y $ is Lindelof, we can choose a countable subcover $ W_{y_{1}}, W_{y_{2}}, \cdot\cdot\cdot W_{y_{m}}, \cdot\cdot\cdot$.  Then the collection $ V_{y_{1}}, V_{y_{2}}, \cdot\cdot\cdot V_{y_{m}}, \cdot\cdot\cdot$ is a countable subcover. Since each $ V_{y} $ is a finite union of sets $ U_{\alpha} $, we also have a countable subcover by sets in $ \{ U_{\alpha} \} $.

Is this correct? Could it be improved?

Comment: What if $X=Y=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology, and $f=id_{\Bbb R}$ ?

Comment: You can prove $X$ is Lindelöf. It need not be compact.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  I do not understand. The question is: $ f $ be a perfect map. Show that if $ Y $ is Lindelof, then $ X $ is compact.

Comment: My point is, its's false. If $Y$ is Lindelöf, so is $X$. But no more than that. The identity is a perfect map...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said: it's false: Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the identity map, where the reals have their usual topology.

$f$ is perfect (any homeomorphism is). The image is Lindelöf (separable metric implies Lindelöf), but the domain is **not** compact.

One *can* prove that in the OP's setup $X$ must be Lindelöf (perfect maps allow us to lift quite a few covering properties from codomain to domain) but the geneeral example above, shows that we cannot "magically" expect the domain to get a stronger property from a weaker one.